# Substitute for unsigned types in Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

In OpenCV, the fastest way to work with a Mat is to first copy it to an array of the appropriate primitive type, something like this:

```
byte[][] array = new byte[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    mat.get(i, 0, array[i]);
}
```

However, this doesn't work in OpenCV4Android with unsigned Mat types (e.g. `8U`), since Java lacks unsigned types.  I could just copy to an array of the next larger primitive type (here, a short) while adding 256 to every element:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[cols];
short[][] array = new short[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    mat.get(i, 0, buf);
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        array[i][j] = (short) (buf[i]+256);
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: using the next larger type makes sense, but why would you add 256?

Comment: Because it's the difference between the signed and unsigned interpretations of a particular 1-byte binary value.  E.g. 0b11111111 is interpreted as -1 signed but 255 unsigned.

Comment: You would only want to add 256 if the "unsigned" value is negative. An easier way is to do  (theByte & 0xff)

Comment: When looking through the api there already seems to be accessors for wider types (like int), did you try to just use those instead? OpenCV might just have solved this for you already.

Comment: I did, but they actually throw an exception if the underlying data type   of the Mat is different.  So I have to use the accessor for byte if I have an unsigned byte Mat.  The OpenCV4Android API is really badly thought-out, and I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't anticipate the unsigned/signed problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually possible to convert the Mat to signed byte before extracting it:

```
mat.convertTo(mat, CvType.CV_8S);
```

Comment: What would the output be?

Answer (score 2):

While indeed Java doesn't support unsigned primitive types, this would make a difference only if you do actual arithmetics with the values. 8 bits are 8 bits, signed or unsigned. If you need to calculate something with the values, yes - you should use a larger type (in fact double of the original) to avoid overflows (signed byte -127:128, unsgined: 0:255) and you should do some conversion to get rid of the "sign part" ( in case of byte & 0xFF).
Edit: This is a general answer, I haven't used OpenCV4Android. While in specific cases it might make sense to work with unsigned types for memory consumption reasons, my guess is that a library will actually output the values you need in the correct form for the platform?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing arithmetic with the values; there's no such thing as a "sign part" and byte & 0xFF does not convert unsigned to signed; the library does not output the correct form for the platform.

Comment: In any case, I have a way to accomplish what I need already - I'm only concerned about speed.

Comment: @1" If you're concerned about speed on Android, you should be doing it in native code...

Comment: That's fair.  However, I'm not going to redo everything in native code, especially since the speed difference is probably not too significant when working with OpenCV's own methods.